# How to use tensorflow to build a deep neural network with the local loss for each layer?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, loss-function

I'm a novice on tensorflow (TF). Recently, I feel confused when I try to use TF to construct my deep model, in which each layer has its own **(local) loss** function.

It seems like many deep models (e.g., CNN) implemented by TF has only one **(global) loss** function, so one can first comput the hidden representations from the input layer to output layer; then obtain the loss; finally, using the existing optimation algorithm and loss to train model.

Unlike those models, I want to use TF to train each layer based on its own local loss. It means when training the current layer, the previous layers' parameters should be fixed.

So my question is how to construct one or, if necessary, several graphs to reaize the above idea?

Any comments and suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using [.compute_gradients(loss,
    var_list)](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/train/GradientDescentOptimizer#compute_gradients) method of the optimizer.

```
wrt_layer1 = opt.compute_gradients ( loss1 , < list of variables >)
wrt_layer2 = opt.compute_gradients ( loss2 , < list of variables >)
....
```

Each returns a list of tuples (gradient, variable).
Concat each of these lists

```
final_grads = wrt_layer1 + wrt_layer2 + .....
```

and finally use [.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars)](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/train/GradientDescentOptimizer#apply_gradients)

```
opt.apply_gradients (final_grads)
```

I guess that might work for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your suggestion seems flexible to address my problem. And a further question is: if I want to compute the gradients and variables of the **i**th layer by using the updated variables of the **i-1**th layer, should I excute the command `.compute_gradients(loss, var_list)` and `.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars)` layer by layer?

Comment: You just have to run the session as needed. It automatically shall take the updated values inside tensors.